# Typescript jQuery AJAX Navigation Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript

Greetings fellow Earthicans,

The following code is used on my website [brianjenkins94.me](http://brianjenkins94.me/) in order to handle simple navigation functionality and after some recent refactoring I seem to have broken the #nav.on("click") event handler and I can't seem to find out the cause.

If anyone could identify why this code is nonfunctional or perhaps provide some insight as to whether there is a better way of going about doing this, **(I'm really interested in proper design and right practice, this bug is just a convenient excuse to make a post and get input)** it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks ahead of time,

Brian

---

```
/// <reference path="jquery.d.ts" />
"use strict";

const SERVERNAME: string = "http://brianjenkins94.me/";
//const DOCUMENTROOT: string = "https://rawgit.com/brianjenkins94/local.blog.com/master/";

class Navigation {
  private body: JQuery;
  private nav: JQuery;
  private navToggle: JQuery;

  constructor(args: any[]) {
    this.body = args[0];
    this.nav = args[1];
    this.navToggle = args[2];
  }

  public init(): void {
    this.stopPropogation();
    this.addClickListener(this.body);
    this.addClickListener(this.navToggle);
    this.addClickListener(this.nav);
    this.addKeyCodeListener(27);
    this.addLinkListener();
  }

  private stopPropogation(): void {
    (this.nav).on("click touchend", function(event: Event): void {
      event.stopPropagation();
    });
  }

  private addClickListener(target: JQuery): void {
    (target).on("click touchend", (event: Event) => {
      if (!(target === (this.body))) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();

        if (target === this.navToggle) {
          (this.body).toggleClass("nav-visible");
          return;
        }
      }
      (this.body).removeClass("nav-visible");
    });
  }

  private addKeyCodeListener(keycode: number): void {
    $(window).on("keydown", function(event: JQueryKeyEventObject): void {
      if (event.keyCode === keycode) {
        (this.body).removeClass("nav-visible");
      }
    });
  }

  private addLinkListener(): void {
    // FIXME: This can be optimized.

    $("#nav .links a").click(function(event: Event): void {

      if (!$(this).hasClass("active")) {
        $("#nav .links a").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");

        document.location.hash = $(this).attr("href");

        switch (document.location.hash) {
          case "#home":
            $.get(SERVERNAME + "home", function(data: string): void {
              $("body").removeClass("nav-visible");
              $("#content").show();
              $("#iframe").html(data);
              console.log("Loaded index.html");
              $(window).scrollTop(0);
            });
            break;
          case "#showcase":
            $.get(SERVERNAME + "showcase", function(data: string): void {
              $("body").removeClass("nav-visible");
              $("#content").hide();
              $("#iframe").html(data);
              console.log("Loaded showcase.html");
              $(window).scrollTop(0);
            });
            break;
          case "#fraise":
            $.get(SERVERNAME + "fraise", function(data: string): void {
              $("#body").removeClass("nav-visible");
              $("#content").hide();
              $("#iframe").html(data);
              console.log("Loaded fraise.html");
              $(window).scrollTop(0);
            });
            break;
          case "#sharpcraft":
            $.get(SERVERNAME + "sharpcraft", function(data: string): void {
              $("#body").removeClass("nav-visible");
              $("#content").hide();
              $("#iframe").html(data);
              console.log("Loaded sharpcraft.html");
              $(window).scrollTop(0);
            });
            break;
          case "#tablature":
            $.get(SERVERNAME + "tablature", function(data: string): void {
              $("#body").removeClass("nav-visible");
              $("#content").hide();
              $("#iframe").html(data);
              console.log("Loaded tablature.html");
              $(window).scrollTop(0);
            });
            break;
          case "#web-design":
            $.get(SERVERNAME + "web-design", function(data: string): void {
              $("#body").removeClass("nav-visible");
              $("#content").hide();
              $("#iframe").html(data);
              console.log("Loaded web-design.html");
              $(window).scrollTop(0);
            });
            break;
          case "#about":
            $.get(SERVERNAME + "about", function(data: string): void {
              $("#body").removeClass("nav-visible");
              $("#content").hide();
              $("#iframe").html(data);
              console.log("Loaded about.html");
              $(window).scrollTop(0);
            });
            break;
          case "#devtools":
            $.get(SERVERNAME + "devtools", function(data: string): void {
              $("#body").removeClass("nav-visible");
              $("#content").hide();
              $("#iframe").html(data);
              console.log("Loaded devtools.html");
              $(window).scrollTop(0);
            });
            break;
          default:
            // No corresponding link
            event.preventDefault();
            $("#body").removeClass("nav-visible");
            break;
        }
      } else {
        // Same link
        $("#nav .links a").removeClass("active");
        $(document.location.hash).click();
        console.log("Simulating " + document.location.hash + " link click.");
      }
    });

    if (document.location.hash.length === 0) {
      $("#home").click();
      console.log("Simulating #home link click.");
    } else {
      $(document.location.hash).click();
      console.log("Simulating " + document.location.hash + " link click.");
    }
  }
}

var Nav: Navigation = new Navigation([$("body"), $("#nav"), $("a[href=\"#nav\"]")]);
Nav.init();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `$("#nav .links a").click(function(event: Event): void {`

Use an arrow function instead i.e. do `$("#nav .links a").click((event: Event): void => {`. This is because the `this` in a JQuery event handler is actually the object that was clicked and not the containing class.

Here is a video on correct use of `this` : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tvocUcbCupA

Comment: Do you think you could expand on this a bit? Am I using ```this``` incorrectly in all contexts, or just in the ones involving jQuery? Is it better practice to always use an arrow function?

Comment: You just need to be careful with event handlers. I've expanded the answer a bit. http://stackoverflow.com/posts/31364157/revisions

Comment: I made the modification you said but there still doesn't appear to be a click listener assigned to $("#nav").

Comment: I'm going to try removing jQuery from the equation. I think it has become too much of a crutch for me that has inhibited my learning of real javascript. Thank you for your help.